# Docker Swarm - Manager unreachable but status still ready

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

I have the following scenario:

3 Nodes (2 Manager & 1 Worker)

Everything works great and I got them visualized. If I kill the worker the status will say down after a few seconds which is correct. If I one of the managers the manager status says unreachable which is correct. But the status still says ready.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

The problem is that you will need 3 manager nodes to make it work.

More here: [Blog Post](https://ml-software.azurewebsites.net/Post/Details/11)